# unable to connect to wifi using raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have a wireless router and not a LAN CONNECTION.so i want to connect my wifi to raspberry pi using USB wifi dongle and unable to do it.I have tried doing it using wifi_config but couldnt open the browser after connection is made.when i open any browser i get an error "couldnt resolve the host"and When i am connecting the wifi in wifi_config i am getting an error "failed AP scan".so,Please find me a solution and suggest me wht to do. I am using a laptop to get connected to my raspberry pi.

Comment: Did you install drivers for your dongle? Is it compatible? [list of compatible ones](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)

Comment: No, I didnt install any drivers and the dongle is campatable with raspberry pi. can pls let me know how can i install the drivers as i m not connected to any network.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on the internet [such as this](http://www.suntimebox.com/raspberry-pi-tutorial-course/week-3/day2-1-wireless-network-setup/)

Comment: The problem is i am unable to update any thing in my raspberry pi ,it is shwng error in openg the sites and i dont now to get it done.Every procedure i follow has a update.but my raspberry couldnt get updated.

Comment: Use ethernet cable

Comment: but i have used it to connect raspberry to laptop.isnt there any other procedure,should i use a monitor(compulsory)

Comment: Does your laptop have WiFi? Use ethernet to connect internet to raspberry (preferably through router, it should have some free spots). Then, via ssh from your laptop, update, download what you wish, go back to original configuration and use wifi dongle on your raspi.

Comment: ok i will connect my ethernet to  raspberry via router.but how can i acces rasbian os of raspberry pi in laptop as raspberry has only one ethernet port

Comment: You have WiFi router, right? Connect to your wifi with your laptop and use ssh normally

Answer (score 2):

So I suppose your router is connected to internet, which means it can provide internet, what needed is you Pi to ask for an IP address using dhcp discovery message, I'm not experienced about wifi_config so I suggest you to turn it back to default.

Then check interfaces manual by `man interfaces`, there you'll find many settings for setting the interface settings which are located at `/etc/network/interfaces`. After that edit the text file interfaces by `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`. Add there a stanza including the details of your router(it's SSID and if exists passphrase. And example I can give to you is :

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "SSID"
    wpa-psk "PASSWORD"
```

If you turn all the other settings to default, this will work for sure. You can get all the meanings of the lines above from `man interfaces` and also from another answer that I provided : [How to setting up wlan0 that automatically turn on when eth0 is switched off?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33275/how-to-setting-up-wlan0-that-automatically-turn-on-when-eth0-is-switched-off/33283#33283)

Comment: i have copied wht u have said but the file doest get saved when i prees ctrlX and then y it is showng some other options as M-D,M-A,M-M,etc.butt if iam choosing one of them its showing error "error couldnt write ,such directory doesnt exists"

Comment: just press enter @SharathVedala

Comment: Press ctrl + O then press ctrl + X it should work @SharathVedala

Comment: Of course don't forget to press enter after pressing ctrl + O ** @SharathVedala